# Sharepoint webservices - Getlistviewitems always return default view

Tags: c#, web-services, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I'm using SharePoint 2013 web services to retrieve elements in a list. It works fine with the default view but I get the same result with other views as well.

This is the soap query I'm using.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetListItems xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
      <listName>{011C5977-B4FE-4044-8EA5-971552602039}</listName>
      <viewName>{A42BE5F6-910E-4D93-8E51-58D43CC8C00A}</viewName>
      <query>
        <Query xmlns="">
          <OrderBy/>
          <Where>
            <Eq>
              <FieldRef Name="FSObjType"/>
              <Value Type="Lookup">0</Value>
            </Eq>
          </Where>
        </Query>
      </query>
      <viewFields>
        <ViewFields xmlns=""/>
      </viewFields>
      <queryOptions>
        <QueryOptions xmlns=""/>
      </queryOptions>
    </GetListItems>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: What do you mean "return default view"? You mean that it gets all items? I think that it is expected behavior because you cannot provide view and query at the same time(View has its own caml query in it).

Comment: Ok so how can i get files (without folder) from a view? Is there a way to find caml query from a view?

Comment: YoU can try to use Views service to get view and then get its query http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/websvcviews.views_members(v=office.14).aspx. But you still have to create new query object dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so like Yevgeniy.Chernobrivets said viewname can't be use with a query. The solution to combine filter and view are to use getView to find the where clause of the desired view and to combine it with yours